# can a single java program send and receive data through two different ports

Tags: java, networking

I programmed a client program which receives just a plain text from the server through port number 2000 (say) in a recieve method in a Router1 class. Now I want to send this data from the Client program to another program say (Client2) through another port number 2001 in a send method of the same class Router1. Is this allowable way to do ?

I get `Connection refused:connect exception`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
class Router{
String str;
public void receive(){
                           try{
                            while(true){
                            Socket so=new Socket("localhost",2000);
                            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
                            str=br.readLine();
                            System.out.println("server has sent:"+str);
                            so.close();}
                                  }catch(IOException e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();}
                }
public void send(){
    int i,index=0,min=100;
    int row=2;
    try{
         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSN2");
         Statement st=cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Table1");
        //rs.absolute(row);
        rs.next();
        rs.next();
        //System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs.getInt(2)+"\t"+rs.getInt(3)+"\t"+rs.getInt(4)+"\t"+rs.getInt(5)+"\t"+rs.getInt(6));
        for( i=2;i<7;i++){  
            int value=rs.getInt(i);
            System.out.println("hello");
                  if(value<min){
                index=i;
                min=value;}
        }
        System.out.println("min is"+min);
        System.out.println("AT index"+index);
        switch(index){
            case 2:
                ioConnect();
                break;
            case 3:
                ioConnect();
                break;
            case 4:
                ioConnect();
                break;
            case 5:
                ioConnect();    
                break;
            case 6:
                ioConnect();
                break;
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void ioConnect(){
    try{
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(2001);
        Socket so=ss.accept();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter the message");
        String str=br.readLine();
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(so.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(str);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
class Router1{
public static void main(String s[]){
    Router obj=new Router();
    obj.receive();
    obj.send();
}
}
```

Comment: Basically it's allowed. But it depends on your code if it will even work!

Comment: Do You use the same socket for both ports?

Comment: @icbytes no i use different sockets

Comment: Then we surely need to see some code.

Comment: i posted the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456343/single-java-program-to-send-and-recieve-plain-text

Answer (score 4):

Sure it's allowed. Connection refused just means there's nothing listening on that port, so your program isn't obviously working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Its  is possible if your Client2 program is running on a different port. For eg there can be two java process running on a same system at different ports. They can always communicate on the ports they are listening on

Comment: I have a Single program named Router1.In Router1 two methods 1.receive 2.send.In recieve port number to get connected to server is 2000 and in send i use 2001 to send to another Program named Router2.

Comment: ROuter1 and Router2 are running on same java process?

Comment: Router1 and Router2 are different programs